# Issue with making an overlay hover effect to a PNG image (transparent) in a parent div with a background color

Tags: html, css, png, overlay, transparency

I believe this is simple but I cannot seem to figure it out. I want to create an overlay hover effect on an image, but I'm having trouble with a PNG image that has the transparency in it. The black background from the parent div element is filling the transparent parts of the PNG image as if the parts of the image are set in opacity: 0 by default.

Here's my html

```
<div class="parent">
<img src="transparent.png"/>
</div>
```

Here's my css

```
.parent {
background-color: #000000;
}
.parent img:hover {
opacity: .7;
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's expected behaviour. What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The black background should not fill the PNG image. It should remain in white as default. The overlay effect due to opacity should only work when I hover on the image. On other images without transparency, obviously, it'll cover the black background from the parent div. That's the same effect I wish to achieve on a transparent image, but I need the transparecy to appear in white color as its default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, not much to say, but the values needs to be changed accordingly, i have just used values to display the function. Read the comments of the codes

```css
.parent {
background-color: #000000;
}
.parent img:hover {
  opacity: .1; /*change this accordingly*/
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
/*Last value of rgba is opacity, 0.0 -> 1.0*/
}

.parent img {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<img src="https://www.lunapic.com/editor/premade/transparent.gif"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies. The opacity: 1 was a typo on my post. It's really .7. Regardless, thank you for your response. Your snippet was the issue that I wish to address. The black background should not fill the PNG image. It should remain in white as default. The overlay effect due to opacity should only work when I hover on the image.

Comment: so you want the image opacity to go through the black and display the white background of the body??

Comment: yes. by default, the transparent parts of the image should appear in white color. My initial code of putting a background-color in the parent div is to try and achieve an overlay effect with black color when I hover on the image.

Comment: @user874737 thats a hard challenge to complete, i might have some ideas, i will see if i can figure it out. Would using javascript be a viable option?

Comment: sure. btw, what I exactly want to do is similar to Facebook's preview of the image before it is uploaded.
Samples: https://i.ibb.co/nRxqVyg/with-overlay.png | https://i.ibb.co/Wgd06BT/no-overlay.png

Comment: @user874737 like this? https://i.gyazo.com/31ced6013da08a82e10e6ca4001b9e66.png

Comment: @user874737 or this? https://i.gyazo.com/f2845574dc3ef8cb6d99c615192622d5.mp4

Comment: Like this, https://i.gyazo.com/f2845574dc3ef8cb6d99c615192622d5.mp4. Although the  black background should not affect the image by default. It should stay as i.gyazo.com/31ced6013da08a82e10e6ca4001b9e66.png until you hover.

Comment: okay so the reverse of the first gif?

https://i.gyazo.com/99f9f17bf1a080771d55b9b85cbea1c2.mp4

Comment: yes, that's the effect with the transparency of the background not all the way down to 0, maybe just .7.

Comment: @user874737 check the answer

Comment: @user874737 no problem, glad i could help! :)